# iOS - UITableView work incorrect between numberOfRowsInSection: and cellForRowAtIndexPath: method

Tags: ios, uitableview

I create a UITableView in a UIView, just using code only (not use IB)

```
 m_tableData = [[UITableView alloc] init];
 m_tableData.dataSource = self; 
 m_tableData.delegate = self;   
 [self addSubview:m_tableData];
```

And

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     NSLog(@"%d", [arrPanelListImg count]);
     return [arrPanelListImg count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"kCell"];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"kCell"] ;


        NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);

    }

return cell;
```

}

And in log screen I see

numberOfRowsInSection: method return 18.
And cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, just run 9 times (fit in screen).

And I found nothing strange in my code. So anybody has any suggestion for me in this case.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: That should be correct.  It doesn't ask you to fill cells with data until it needs to display them.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `UITableView`'s `initWithFrame:style:` method - this is the designated initializer for the `UITableView` class.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that

```
m_tableData = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

When I change to it, nothing different with my original result. It is really strange, this is the first time I see this error and still have no solution for it.

Edit: 
- Just remove checking condition cell == nil and work correctly.